# How get access to variable in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have next Angular JS controllers structure:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
   <div ng-controller="mainCtrlTst">
      // here is loaded HTML file  
   </div>
</div>
```

**HTML file:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <input ng-model="formData.map" value="">
</div>
```

For default `formData.map` containts address "USA, New York"
I have method `Save()` in `MainController`, but when I call this method I get:

```
console.log(formData.map); // undefined
```

How I can get value `formData.map` from input?

Comment: Is `MainController` nested within itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your model in controller like

```
$scope.formData = {
    map: ''
};
```

And then use it in the view.

And then check in the save method by following code

```
console.log($scope.formData.map);
```

Hope you will not get undefined.

Comment: I have declared `$scope.formData`

Comment: Still you get undefined when use console.log($scope.formData.map);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in `MainController`:

```
console.log($scope.formData.map);
```

To be more precise, in your `save()` function inside the controller do as follows:

```
$scope.save = function(){
    console.log($scope.formData.map);
}
```

To know more about `$scope`, visit : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope